# Error:Failed to find datanode suggest to check cluster health

Tags: php, hadoop, curl

I have written the following code for creating /writing a file to hdfs through php. Used the following API for reference https://github.com/Yujiro3/WebHDFS

But the code gives the following error and fails to upload file in the required directory:

```
{"RemoteException":{"exception":"IOException","javaClassName":"java.io.IOException","message":"Failed to find datanode, suggest to check cluster health."}
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:28:39 GMT
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:28:39 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:28:39 GMT
Date: Mon, 07 Mar 2016 21:28:39 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

require 'WebHDFS.php';
$hdfs = new WebHDFS ();

$hdfs -> put('/user/webuser/sample.txt', "sample \ n test \ n");
?>
```

What correction should I make?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your hdfs datanode is unreachable and has nothing to do with your php.

From your console attempt to create a folder without PHP, like so:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs:///demofolder
```

I'm guessing that this will fail since the data node is down.

Check your hdfs-site.xml file to see where dfs.datanode.data.dir is pointing to and make sure that location exists. Then in the same file look for dfs.datanode.address. Mine was 0.0.0.0:50010

Try telnet to that ip port:

```
telnet 0.0.0.0 50010
```

You should be able to connect. If you can not then you need to start your data node. I was able to do this by running:

```
/usr/hdp/2.1.2/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs datanode
```

The location of your "hdfs" may be different than mine.
Assuming that you have that started up trying creating a folder again. If that works then try your php again.

One last thing that I noticed was in the WebHDFS.php it has defaults for host and port for hdfs.

```
public function __construct($host='localhost', $port='50070') {
    $this->_host = $host;
    $this->_port = $port;
}
```

Make sure your configurations line up with the defaults unless you are going to override them.
Good luck.