# pyhdfs.HdfsIOException: Failed to find datanode, suggest to check cluster health. excludeDatanodes=null

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run hadoop using docker provided here:

https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop

I use the following command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

to up the service and am able to access it and browse file system using: `localhost:9870`. Problem rises whenever I try to use `pyhdfs` to put file on HDFS. Here is my sample code:

```
hdfs_client = HdfsClient(hosts = 'localhost:9870')

# Determine the output_hdfs_path
output_hdfs_path = 'path/to/test/dir'

# Does the output path exist? If not then create it
if not hdfs_client.exists(output_hdfs_path):
      hdfs_client.mkdirs(output_hdfs_path)

hdfs_client.create(output_hdfs_path + 'data.json', data = 'This is test.', overwrite = True)
```

If test directory does not exist on HDFS, the code is able to successfully create it but when it gets to the `.create` part it throws the following exception:

```
pyhdfs.HdfsIOException: Failed to find datanode, suggest to check cluster health. excludeDatanodes=null
```

What surprises me is that my code is able to create the empty directory but fails to put the file on HDFS. My `docker-compose.yml` file is exactly the same as the one provided in the github repo. The only change I've made is in the `hadoop.env` file where I change:

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
```

to

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:9000
```

I have seen this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854600/errorfailed-to-find-datanode-suggest-to-check-cluster-health) on sof and tried the following command:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs:///demofolder
```

which works fine in my case. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the default `CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000` setting.
Works fine for me after adding a forward slash to the paths

```py
import pyhdfs

fs = pyhdfs.HdfsClient(hosts="namenode")
output_hdfs_path = '/path/to/test/dir'

if not fs.exists(output_hdfs_path):
       fs.mkdirs(output_hdfs_path)

fs.create(output_hdfs_path + '/data.json', data = 'This is test.')

# check that it's present

list(fs.walk(output_hdfs_path))
[('/path/to/test/dir', [], ['data.json'])]
```